# Does separating mesh remove texture?

Tags: mesh, texturing

I'm working on cleaning up some scans of artifacts and right now am working on a pair of shoes. The issue with the shoes is that when the scans were taken, some of the table they were sitting on was picked up, so I'm trying to remove it so it's just the shoes.

The steps I've taken so far are separating the two shoes, removing the vertices, and then filling any gaps, however when I try to go back to seeing the texture over the mesh, it's gone. Is this because I'm separating the mesh and somehow erasing the texture? Or is there something else I'm missing?

I'm new to this kind of stuff and working on trial and error, so if someone can explain what is happening and a possible solution that would be great.

Cheers!

Comment: We'll need to see some images to see exactly what you mean. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Answer (score 1):

No, a texture is something independent of a mesh.  I think the right way to think about a texture (generally speaking, at least) is as a parameter for one or more materials.  If you look at the texture image in an image editor, you'll see that it's still there, and that nothing you do to the mesh is going to change that.

What might be happening here is that UV mapping is being destroyed.  Generally, textures use UV mapping to create correspondences between the 3D mesh and and the 2D image, so that the image can be mapped onto the mesh.  But if you're deleting and creating geometry, new geometry isn't going to have any UV coordinates specified.  And if you create a face between two old faces, that were parts of different islands, that new face may default to very weird UV.

But there is another possibility, which is that you're losing proper material assignments.  If a mesh object is using multiple materials, and you create a new face, Blender cannot know what material you want the new face to have.  It uses some reasonable guesses, but those can be wrong.  If Blender guesses wrong, then your new faces may be assigned a material that doesn't reference the material using the texture image, or perhaps one that uses the texture image in a different way.